# Extracting string data from text C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Im currently writing a c++ program that needs to extract string and numeric data from a text file. The format of the data is the following;

```
3225 C9+     ELECTR  C8      C        *      1.00E-6  -0.30       0.0
```

first entry is an integer, next 5 entries are strings and the last 3 are floats. No string is ever greater than 7 characters long.

I am reading the file line by line and then extracting the data using;

```
sscanf(ln.c_str(),"%d  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %e  %e  %e",
&rref[numre],&names[numre][0],&names[numre][1],&names[numre][2],&names[numre][3],
&names[numre][4],&nums[numre][0],&nums[numre][1],&nums[numre][2]);
```

this works fine untill I meet a line like;

```
  3098 SIC2H3+ ELECTR  SIC2H2  H        *      1.50E-7  -0.50       0.0
```

where one of the entrys is the full 7 characters long. In this case I get;

```
names[3097][0] = "SIC2H3+ELECTR"
```

and,

```
names[3097][1] = "ELECTR"
```

Anybody got any ideas...they will be much appreciated!!

Comment: Are the fields seperated by a tab? or just spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely problem is in the declaration of `names`: if you declared it as holding seven characters or less, and forgot to allocate space for terminating zero, you'd get the results that you are describing.

```
char names[MAX][4][7]
```

will have enough space for strings of length 6 or less; for strings of length 7, you need

```
char names[MAX][4][8]
```

Comment: on a side note...why have/what is a terminating zero?

Comment: @JoshuaGreenhalgh C strings do not store length along with the characters, so in order to support variable-length strings, a convention was made to put zero, a non-printable character, after the last meaningful character in a string. All input routines do that, and all output routines expect a zero at the end. That's why you need to allocate `max_length+1` chars to store a string of `max_length`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, what you're saying is correct, except replace zero with null. They are referred to as null terminated strings. Saying zero is somewhat misleading when talking about string terminations in C/C++. I would also be careful about assuming that all input and output routines "do the right thing" with nulls and string termination, as that is very dependent on the specific library. Cheers.

Comment: @user11686: They are actually referred to as `NUL` terminated strings, which is the same as `'\0'`, or zero.